# Ways to develop a review system in Android

Tags: android, review

I am developing an android application that searches for various places. The app needs to have a review system where users write reviews about the places they've visited as well as view the reviews submitted by other users. It'd also be necessary to only show a few reviews in the activity and load more once button,say  is pressed.I dont know where to start. Any help'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start with a project ;) You see its a classic client-server app so you gonna need a server with own server-API or REST API. That's for uploading/downloading reviews. For all other just try to do something then you'll be more certain with your questions